# Use HighCharts several times

Tags: angular, highcharts, components

Bonjour,

I have a question about using the Highcharts library.
In my angular application I have 3 tabs (sale / rental / rental & sale)
In each tab I have to display 3 identical diagrams except the datas which change because they come from my API.

Here's what I've done now but it only works on the first component of the first tab.

I think my problem is that I put the chart options in the ngOnInit?

My app

```
--mls
mls.module
   assetsStatus
      --location
      --vente
      --locationEtVente
   data
      --counter
      --graphic
   navigation
      --header
```

graphic.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.graphicDatasObservable.subscribe( datas => {
      this.data = datas;
      console.log(this.data)
    });
    // this.charts = 
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
          type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Fruit Consumption'
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Fruit eaten'
          }
      },
      series: [{
          name: 'toto',
          data: [1, 0, 4]
      }]
  });
```

graphic.html

```
<div id="container" style="height: 150px; margin: 2px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the official `highcharts-angular` wrapper while working with the angular.

To achieve that with the wrapper you could just update the `chartOptions` with the new data set every time you are changing the tab.

**Docs:**
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

**Live demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-w3jrpf

Comment: Thank you very much for this example but I would like to display 3 graphics per tab. I have some problems with the frameworks to know where to place my code. I manage to display one diagram but not all the 9

Comment: Then you could just create three `highcharts-chart` components and pass a different `chartOptions` to each component depending on the chart configuration and its data.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-w3jrpf